How do I install numpy with meson options
In numpy >=1.24, SVML was added which affects Intel Linux machines. I need to opt out of SVML for improved accuracy in a specific project.
I'd like to pip install, or specify a pyproject dependency for numpy in a way which passes the meson option disable-svml to the build process.
Note: there is issue 23362 open in numpy which discusses an environment variable to opt out of lower precision SVML at runtime. But until this feature is implemented, this is my current workaround.
I've found pip's --global-option and --config-settings (requires --use-pep517) arguments, but haven't figured it out yet.
